# Anyone got tips on how to remove a bayonet lightbulb form a twist socket?

Tags: light-fixture, stuck

I made the mistake of putting a bayonet lightbulb into a twist socket and I can’t get it out. It’s above my bed so it would be preferable to not break it.

[image]

Comment: Have you twisted back slightly and pulled down? (And bulbs are pretty robust, so they aren't easy to break.)

Comment: When you twist the lightbulb in the reverse direction, hold it gently but give a persistent force to tilt it a little. It was probably how you got it into the socket in the first place. Also, wear a working glove, and put down a plastic sheet to cover your bed.

Answer (score 3):

If the steps already suggested don’t work then breaking the bulb envelope and twisting the metal remains with pointed pliers can work - it did for me.

**Make sure that circuit is off** before breaking the bulb and applying pliers.

Covering the bed or catching the bits in a box etc is a crucial step.

Comment: and cover the bed

Comment: @P2000 yes, I used a medium sized box for the bits to fall into, will add that.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a BC globe in an ES socket

Wiggle it in a circular motion as you try to unscrew it, try both directions.